# type declaration type object is not subscriptable list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def words(string: str) -> list[str]:
    return string.split(' ')
```

Running this raises the error

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I correctly specify that the output will be a list of strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*For now*, you need to write the following:

```
from typing import List


def words(string: str) -> List[str]:
    return string.split(' ')
```

Note the capitalisation of `List` vs `list`. There’s a [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) for making your code work going forward, starting with Python 3.9.